# How to parse XML leaving particular tags or their contents as plain text?

Tags: python, xml

I am parsing a document of an XML format which supports some HTML-like tags, inline formatting tags included. I would like to parse all the tags the normal way but keep content of `p` tags unparsed so I could work with the structured data the structure-aware way and fall back to plain string operations for textual content and formatting. E.g.

```
<root>
    <data1><field1>qwerty</field1> <field2>qwerty</field2> </data1>
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a> <em><strong>amet</strong> consectetuer</em></p>
    </body>
</root>
```

should result in a tree where the root element contains a data1 element and a body element; data1 element contains field1 and field2 elements (the spaces after these tags should be discarded); body element contains 2 p elements but the p elements (all of them) contain no child tags and expose their entire content as text strings.

I.e. given the second p tag object I'd like the following to be true:

```
p.text == 'Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a> <em><strong>amet</strong> consectetuer'
```

It doesn't really matter if this is going to be achieved via a "treat everything enclosed in a p tag as plain-text" or a "treat a, em and strong tags as plain text wherever they are" kind of rule although I feel interested in knowing both ways.

In fact the tags mentioned are not the only ones relevant, I need to be able to specify names of the tags the principle will apply to.

How do I parse XML this way in Python?

It doesn't matter for me which XML library to use. I haven't worked with XML in Python before and haven't chosen one so far. I am using lxml now (because I've read it can decode ASCII files automatically and has better XPath support, it also won't mess with namespaces shortcuts the way ElementTree does) but there are so many of them (ElementTree, MiniDOM, lxml, Untangle, BeautifulSoup and other) I don't really know which one suits me better. By the way, whoever knows of a good comparative overview of Python XML libraries I'd be grateful if you could share a link to it in a comment.

Comment: could you try using bs4 beautifulsoup? i have used it and got that kind of output .

Comment: yeah it was html , but xml doesnot seems so different.

Comment: @JainilPatel Perhaps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
    <data1><field1>qwerty</field1> <field2>qwerty</field2> </data1>
    <body>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        <p>Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a> <em><strong>amet</strong> consectetuer</em></p>
    </body>
</root>'''

TEST_STRINGS = ['<p>Lorem ipsum</p>',
                '<p>Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a> <em><strong>amet</strong> consectetuer</em></p>']


def _add_text_before_traversing_tree(e):
    return e.tag in ['p']


def _handle_attrib(attrib):
    result = ''
    for k, v in attrib.items():
        result += '{}="{}"'.format(k, v)
    return ' ' + result if result else ''


def _element_to_text(e, tree_fragments):
    tree_fragments.append('<{}'.format(e.tag))
    if not e.attrib:
        tree_fragments.append('>')
    tree_fragments.append(_handle_attrib(e.attrib))
    add_text_now = _add_text_before_traversing_tree(e)
    if add_text_now:
        tree_fragments.append(e.text if e.text else '')
    for child in list(e):
        _element_to_text(child, tree_fragments)
    if not add_text_now:
        if not e.attrib:
            tree_fragments.append(e.text if e.text else '')
        else:
            tree_fragments.append('>' + e.text if e.text else '')
    tree_fragments.append('</{}>'.format(e.tag))
    tree_fragments.append(e.tail.strip() if e.tail else '')


def element_to_text(e):
    """ Traverse element tree and return a string representation of the tree"""
    tree_fragments = []
    _element_to_text(e, tree_fragments)
    tree_fragments = [x for x in tree_fragments if len(x) > 0]
    return ''.join(tree_fragments)


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
p_elements = root.findall('./body/p')
for idx, p in enumerate(p_elements):
    element_as_text = element_to_text(p)
    print('Original text  : ' + TEST_STRINGS[idx])
    print('Element as text: ' + element_as_text)
    print('')
    # now you need to create a new element,
    # attach it to the parent element ('body'),
    # set its new text and remove the current element
```

output

```
Original text  : <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
Element as text: <p>Lorem ipsum</p>

Original text  : <p>Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a> <em><strong>amet</strong> consectetuer</em></p>
Element as text: <p>Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a><em><strong>amet</strong>consectetuer</em></p>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it turns  `<a href="http://example.com">sit</a>` into `<a>sit href="http://example.com"</a>`.

Comment: @Ivan Bug was fixed. As you can see the structure is fine now. The only difference is where your original HTML fragment comes with extra spaces

Comment: Lovely. Thanks. The space should be preserved, however. Em/strong tags don't insert spaces themselves, the input and the result are rendered differently, the result becomes `Dolor sitametconsectetuer` (with particular parts of "sitametconsectetuer" decorated in bald, italics or as a link) without spaces between the words if you discard the spaces between the tags.

Comment: @Ivan I think the point with the spaces (Example `sit</a> <em>`) that they dropped by the parser (ElementTree) so they can not be reproduced.

Comment: Then the problem is not solved. I am going to try to invent a way. In fact it doesn't drop them normally. I've written another script (with lxml) which does a little bit different job on the same file (it serializes the entire document back to XML source before working with the text) and it won't even pretty-print a tag unless there already are no such spaces nor free text (anything but sequential tags with no spaces between them)  within it.

Comment: @Ivan I think there is a very trivial solution... `ET.tostring(p).strip()`. Output: `'<p>Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a> <em><strong>amet</strong> consectetuer</em></p>'`

Comment: So this means ET.tostring(p) does the whole job (and strip removes leading and trailing spaces if any), we don't even need the code in the answer?

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to assign the value (with inline tags in it) back to the element after having made some changes in it perhaps? Whatever, please edit the answer and add the tostring way as an alternative solution so other people interested would  see it without having to read the comments.

Comment: Yes. You need to remove the current `p` and create a new one using the text you get from tostring. See b'<p>Dolor <a href="http://example.com">sit</a> <em><strong>amet</strong> consectetuer</em></p>'